# SQL computing on two columns data and updating third's value

Tags: python, sqlite

I am aiming to compute some math on 2 columns and updating the database with its results on a 3 column.  I am using SQLITE3 for the db.  The math is currently trivial so managed to get the below SQL UPDATE function to update 40000 rows of a database.  As the math get more complex, I would aim to compute the math in python after querying the database on the two columns and updating that third row afterward.  What is the best way to update that third column?  if looping across all rows, the SET function tends to update the entire column with the value of the last loop.  Thanks much...

Current SQL code to UPDATE ebitev and capreturn columns with simple math done on input from earlier columns.

```
db = SQL("sqlite:///formula.db")

inventories=db.execute("SELECT ticker, ebit, ev, ppnenet, fcf, workingcapital FROM equity")

"""liste=[]"""

for inventory in inventories:
    ebit = inventory["ebit"]
    ev = inventory["ev"]
    ppnenet = inventory["ppnenet"]
    workingcapital = inventory["workingcapital"]
    fcf = inventory["fcf"]

    if ev == 'NULL':
        db.execute("UPDATE equity SET ebitev='NULL'")
    else:
        ebitev = ebit / ev
        """liste.append(ebitev)"""
        db.execute("UPDATE equity SET ebitev=ebit/ev")

    if ppnenet == 'NULL' or workingcapital == 'NULL':
        db.execute("UPDATE equity SET capreturn='NULL'")
    else:
        db.execute("UPDATE equity SET capreturn=ebit/(ppnenet+workingcapital)")

    if fcf == 'NULL':
        db.execute("UPDATE equity SET fcfyield='NULL'")
    elif ev == 'NULL':
        db.execute("UPDATE equity SET fcfyield='NULL'")
    else:
        db.execute("UPDATE equity SET fcfyield=fcf/ev")
```

Comment: If you use a SQL `NULL` instead of a *string* `'NULL'` in your column values it becomes a lot simpler...

Comment: But anyways, all your updates update the *entire* table. If you want to limit it to just one row, you need an appropriate `WHERE`.

Comment: thanks much.  that helped